# ConcurrencyFailureException : Deadlock while adding large no of rows in batches

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading, transactions

I have built a rest-ful service to insert large rows. To insert large no of rows I am using insertion in batches. What might cause the deadlock in this snippet of the restful service.

```
    final SqlMapClient sqlMapClient = getSqlMapClientTemplate().getSqlMapClient();
    sqlMapClient.startTransaction();
    sqlMapClient.startBatch();

    //data is of size say 10,000 i am dividing into 500 and inserting
    do {
        data500 = next 500 of data
        getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("insertData", data500);  
    }while(data500 is not empty)

    sqlMapClient.executeBatch();
    sqlMapClient.commitTransaction();
```

But I am getting this error :

```
 
Description : org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException: SqlMapClient operation; SQL [];   
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.   
--- Check the insertData-InlineParameterMap.   
--- Check the statement (update failed).   
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction (Process ID 3121) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
```

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks indicate a program design problem. The database creates transactions which lock data as the data is modified. If you modify data 'A' and then data 'B', the database will have both of those data points locked. Depending on your database, and settings, the actual locks for 'A' and 'B' may be individual records, groups of records (pages), or even whole tables.

If your transaction has modifed 'A' already, and is now trying to modify 'B', but some other program has modified 'B' already, and is now trying to modify 'A', then you have a deadlock.

Some databases (like DB2) indicate there is a deadlock even though it may just be a lock timeout (a process tried for 60 seconds to get a lock, but failed). DB2 has special sub-codes to indicate what the underlying deadlock cause was.

The only solution for the deadlock is for the database to choose one of the processes to kill, and let the other one through. Your process has been killed.

The deadlock problem indicates a program design problem. It is a well-known problem, and the only reliable solution is to ensure that all of your programs get locks on data in the same order as each other. This way you will not get deadlocks. Another common reason for deadlocks is programs that do not commit their work at appropriate places in the logic.

EDIT - **In your case, you claim you are inserting them in batches of 500, but your begin/commit are at the beginning and end of *everything*. You need to put the start/execute Batch and start/commit Transaction *inside* the loop. You are holding the locks on *all* the records being inserted**

```
//data is of size say 10,000 i am dividing into 500 and inserting
do {
    sqlMapClient.startTransaction();
    sqlMapClient.startBatch();

    data500 = next 500 of data
    getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("insertData", data500);  

    sqlMapClient.executeBatch();
    sqlMapClient.commitTransaction();
}while(data500 is not empty)
```

Alternatively, deadlocks are 'retryable' errors, if you get a deadlock, you can rerun the SQL and get your results (hopefully without a deadlock this time).

Comment: Edited to include 'fix' for your particular case (you were locking *all 10000 or so* records (plus probably an elevated table lock)

Comment: but i want either all the 10000 to be entered or none should be entered. but in this case if you commit after every batch then there is a possibility that only some of them are inserted.

Comment: A very real possibility is that, as you start inserting records, you lock the rows/pages you are inserting in to. But, at a certain point, the database decides that you have so many locks it is not efficient to track them individually, but to escalate them to a single full table lock. If any other process was modifying, or even possibly selecting from that table, then you have a deadlock condition.

Comment: >>> the database decides that you have so many locks it is not efficient to track them but to escalate them to a single full table lock.... But how can it take a full lock say when another process has the lock on say table's clustered index

Comment: In many databases it is possible to specify the lock condition for the operation *before* you begin the operation. For SQLServer, investigate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: lets say i am doing two heavy 2 transactions with loop of insert records. At some point in T1 it acquired a lock on P1 and T2 acquires a lock on P2. T1 wants to insert into P2 and T2 wants to insert into P1. How can you progromatically handle this.